# How can I rename the org file and delete the org

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch script that can simply copy and rename the file if there is a new content form the old file. The old file get deleted and the new file become.

I used the following, but i keep getting it's incorrect for rename and delete

```
@echo
;ren "C:\file.txt"  "C:\newfilename.txt"
MOVE   "C:\newfilename*.txt"  "C:\newfolder" 
del c:\file.txt
```

Comment: Please further explain the incorrectness?  In DOS, the MOVE command should be able to do something like MOVE "c:\file.txt" "C:\new folder\newfilename.txt"

Answer (score 0):

The new name on a `ren` command is just the name - ou can't specify the directory, so

```
ren "C:\file.txt"  "newfilename.txt"
```

should work for you.

Note that a leading semicolon will be ignored. To remark-out a line, use `REM` not `;`

There is no apparent reason that the `del` command should have failed. Please re-try and post the exact message you see.